# MVC 3 Razor DropdownListFor - How to "filter" the view after value is selected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

So I took some advice to create a DropDownListFor element in my view, which meant to create a model view called

**MODEL**
`class StudentModelView`.

I have two properties.

```
StudentID{get;set;}
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SelectPeopleList { get;set;}
```

I get the list to populate nicely with this code

**VIEW**

```
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.StudentID, Model.SelectPeopleList,"--Select Students--", new Dictionary<string,object>{ {"class","dropdowns"},{"id","selectPeopleDDL"}})  

//NEED A BUTTON TO SUBMIT
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {


            return View(new StudentModelView());
        }
```

1. What kind of button do I need to make it post
2. After posting, how do I update my view to show the new filtered list? Am I missing a POST controller or just ajax? What's the best approach?

Comment: If all you are doing is filtering views, you should try GET instead of POST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it all using jquery, but here is couple of pointers:

You should wrap your filter in a form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Home", "Index", FormMethod.Get))
{
  @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.StudentID, Model.SelectPeopleList,"--Select Students--", new Dictionary<string,object>{ {"class","dropdowns"},{"id","selectPeopleDDL"}})
  <input type="submit" value="Go" />
}
```

the submit button is not a must, you could just use jquery to submit whenever the value of the dropdown changes

in your controller:

```
public ActionMethod Index(int? studentID)
{
  var model = new StudentModelView 
  {
    StudentId = studentID, 
    SelectPeopleList=GetListFiltered(studentId)  
  }

  return(model);
}
```

Comment: +1, I use a similar approach but have jquery call an action that returns a partial view and then appends it to a div on my page, makes the loading look more slick :), see here [link]http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: @RobJohnson same here, most of these filters just get rendered using ajax in my application

Comment: Thanks! I also used a partial view for the load. I Just didn't want to clutter the explanation by adding another variable.